# Is there a simple way to access a div-tag inside another div that contains ul und li-tags?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, tags

I'm trying to scrape a shop-list from a website (the list can only be shown when you enter a zip-code) using python and beautiful soup. When I view the page source or expect the elements I have this structure

```html
<div id ="storelist" class>
   <ul> 
        <li id ="00021455" class>
         .
         .
         .
              <div class ="wr-store-details">
                  <h3> class "Store abc"</h3>
                  <span> class ="20005 dc">
                  <span> class ="LA">
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I'm struggling how to access the second `<div class ="wr-store-details">` to scrape his 3 elements.

I have tried to run the script below but actually

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv 
import requests 

URL = "http:www.abc.com"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 

store_details_tab = []  # a list to store store_details-tab 

table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'storelist'}) 

for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'store_details'}): 
    store_details = {} 
    store_details['store_name'] = row.div.text 
    store_details['store_address'] = row.span.text 
    store_details['store_city'] = row.span.text 
    store_details_tab.append(store_details) 

filename = 'store_details_tab.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['store_name','store_address','store_city']) 
    w.writeheader() 
    for store_details in store_details_tab: 
        w.writerow(store_details)
```

I'm expecting a csv file with store_name, store_city and store_zip

> Error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

---

Comment: If that is the real HTML, the errors in it may confuse the scraper.

Comment: Why are you opening the file with `'b'`? `open(filename, 'wb')` Try remove the `b`

Comment: @mignoncharly share your website link or share full raw html data.

Comment: @furas system saying text too long ...how can I post the entire error

Comment: Post Your `url` in the question which you're trying to scrape

Comment: you are right b is for binary mode what i don't want (will remove it)
 ok but I can't copy here is the link to the picture ...  https://ibb.co/N68qmgm


link -> https://www.haagendazs.us/locator/shops  there are about 250 shops